How to get SMS faster than a built-in reader
I need to receive an SMS in my app and prevent it from reaching the built-in reader. I tried changing the priority but it didn't help
Here's all my code:
MainActivity.java:
package com.example.sms3;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import android.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 1000) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}

ReceiveSms.java:
package com.example.sms3;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if(bundle != null) {
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                        Toast.makeText(context, msg_from + msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

}

AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SMS3"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".ReceiveSms"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>


......................................................................................................................................................................................................

"…prevent it from reaching the built-in reader." – That is not possible in Android since version 4.4, KitKat. The built-in gets a special broadcast that no other app gets, so you wouldn't ever have a chance to stop it.

Then SMS isn't what you want.  I'd look into push messaging.  Or you can look into port based SMS, which isn't generally displayed by the SMS app.
